# How to use a credential file without pushing it to repository

Tags: django, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I am building a Django web app that is deployed on GCP (google cloud platform). I need to use the google cloud storage bucket to store files generated from the app, So I added the code to settings.py

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'credential.json')
```

In the code, credential.json is referred to. Currently, I put the credential file in the project directory on my computer and it works fine. But now I need to push the project to a public repository for project handoff and I can’t push the credential file because it contains the private key to the cloud storage bucket. What should I do to make the program run normally without pushing the credential file to the repository or the file being accessible by other people?

Answer (score 0):

Don't push the credential files and tell the user to create it in the project documentation.

A common pattern is to provide an example file with dummy data to help uses to understand the structure of the file.
You will have a documentation like this:

> Copy the *credential.example.json* as *credential.json* and fill it with your server settings.

```json
// file: credentials.example.json 
{
    "token": "obviously not my token",
    "email": "foo@example.org",
}
```

Comment: will we be able to run my project without pushing the credential file in repository.
please bear with me, as I am a beginner